# Is there a way to SQL this?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in the following format:

```
c_time,             c_id
-------------------------
2009-01-01 12:30,   123
2009-01-01 12:31,   125
2009-01-01 12:32,   123

2009-01-02 12:31,   124
2009-01-02 12:32,   123
2009-01-02 12:33,   124
```

The `id` corresponds to a value in text.

1. How can I write a query to count the number of occurence per date?
2. And how can I have the id replaced with the text it corresponds to (equivalent to an excel vlookup)?

I have tried to write the query and would want to see how others would do.

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: Share what you have tried so far.

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: For Postgres: `select id, count(distinct date_and_time::date) from the_table group by id`

Comment: for mysql try this query
`select count(id),date from <your_table_name> group by date`

Comment: Database is Big Query

Answer (score 1):

```
select date, count(distinct id)
from tbl
group by cast(date as date) --this forces to remove the time
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql query
`select count(id),date from <your_table_name> group by date`

Answer (score 0):

Using SSMS as DBMS.

You could also take advantage of using [COUNT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [OVER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [common table expession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and DISTINCT.

```
--Creating the table to hold your values 
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
[date] DATE,
[time] TIME,
[id] BIGINT
)
-- Inserting values
INSERT INTO #tmpTable
VALUES 
('2009-01-01', '12:30', 123),
('2009-01-01', '12:31', 125 ),
('2009-01-01', '12:32', 123 ),
('2009-01-02', '12:31', 124 ),
('2009-01-02', '12:32', 123 ),  
('2009-01-02', '12:33', 124 )

-- Common table expression
WITH CTE 
AS 
(SELECT [date], [time], [id], COUNT([date]) OVER(Partition by [date],[id] order by 
[id]) AS rn FROM #tmpTable
)

SELECT DISTINCT [date], [id], [rn] 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY id
```